# Paging or Using Skip in Azure Cosmos

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

Has anyone been able to determine the equivalent of [Gremlin Skip](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#skip-step) in Azure Cosmos? It's not listed on [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin-support) and I was thinking it's just outdated. I did try doing a query such as `g.V().hasLabel('the_label').has('the_property', eq('the_value')).skip(some_number)` and it errors out as such `Unable to find any method 'skip'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your link in the Apache TinkerPop documentation:

> The skip()-step is analogous to range()-step save that the higher end range is set to -1.

with these examples:

```
gremlin> g.V().values('age').order().skip(2)
==>32
==>35
gremlin> g.V().values('age').order().range(2, -1)
==>32
==>35
```

Comment: This will produce the same error I got because `skip` seems not supported. The error is `Unable to find any method 'skip'`. I was wondering if MS uses another method name that is not documented.

Comment: the example is trying to show that you can call `range(2,-1)` which is in the list of supported steps instead of `skip(2)` - you get the same result. are you saying that calling `range(2, -1)` produces a  "Unable to find any method 'skip`" error?

Comment: Ah! Gotcha. Thanks @stephen.